Append dict to Chainmap during loop
I have a loop that creates a dictionary based on a directory.
I like to save the results in a json with some other data, and I want them to be chained.
The loop is in a function, which is called upon in the final dict which will become the json.
The best structure I have found for this is a Chainmap, but I can't seem to update, add or append to it.
Is there a way I can do this?
Or do I have to save the dictionaries in a list and then add more code to remove the "[" and "]" in my final dict?
The loop for the chainmap looks like this:
def chained_dictionary_funtion(path):
    chained_dict = collections.ChainMap()
    for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            try:
                entry = {
                        "name": filename
                   }
                #chained_dict.update(entry)
            except:
                 raise
    return chained_dict

Edits:
The desired results should look like this:
chained_dictionaries={"name": "somefilename"}, 
{"name": "somefilename"}, {"name": "somefilename"}

The end dict/ overall result would be:
{ "id": user_input,
"names": function_that_makes_a_list,
"all Data": [
"id": user_input,
"conforms": "always the same",
chained_dictionary_funtion(path)
]
}

I tried to use .update() or .append() but both don't seem to work with collections.chainmap()
In both cases I created a chainmap like
chained_dict= collections.ChainMap()

outside the loop.
I tried:
for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            entry = {
                "name": "#" + filename
                #more data
            }
            chained_dict= collections.ChainMap(entry)
        except:
             raise

but it always just enters the last entry (which makes sense.)
I thought about trying with some i++ but I am not sure where I would start.
It does say that

All of the usual dictionary methods are supported. In addition, there is a maps attribute, a method for creating new subcontexts, and a property for accessing all but the first mapping:

maps
A user updateable list of mappings. The list is ordered from first-searched to last-searched. It is the only stored state and can be modified to change which mappings are searched. The list should always contain at least one mapping.
But when I tried:
chained_dict= collections.ChainMap()
for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            entry = {
                "name": "#" + filename
                #more data
            }
            chained_dict.maps(entry) #or col=chained_dict.maps(entry)
        except:
             raise

It didn't work.

Please show your desired result and what you tried.

Are you sure you really need ChainMap? I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, but I don't see how ChainMap would be useful for it. Why not just an ordinary dictionary?

@Barmar I do need a ChaimMap or something that looks like it, since it will be entered into a bigger thing at the end. The format is sadly not something I decided but something I have to abide by. I could use a list or dict, if I knew how to remove the "outside layer"(If that makes sense) while entering it into a json/ nested dict.

The maps() method doesn't take any arguments. It just returns a list of the existing maps in the ChainMap.

It's still not clear what your desired result is.

To append a dict to a ChainMap, use the the new_child method and specify keyword argument m as the new dict you would like to append to the ChainMap. Here is a copy of your code with this implemented.
However, I do not understand why you want to use a ChainMap for this, if you are creating a new dictionary for the sole purpose of appending it to an existing ChainMap. Why not just manually apend entries into a single dictionary?

I am iterating through a large amount of files and would like to automate most if not all. The script is supposed to be used by people who aren't familiar with the structure of the end file, so any manual inserts are undesirable.
I am really only using chainmap, because I want no external data structure (like a list) around the dictionaries, while still appending them to one object which can be inserted into a final dictionary.
I have been sitting on this issue a while, and might be overlooking other easier ways to do it. I edited my post to show what the final dict is supposed to look like.

In that case, calling new_child as mentioned in my post should work just fine.

It worked! Thank you!
